# cocoapods Dependency Analysis Error

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

One day when I open my Swift workspace, this error occurs all the time, I can't clean even do anything. I'm falling apart.

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this issue by the following step:

```
1. stash local changes
2. stash apply
3. pod install
```

Then everything work well.

Comment: Hope this can help somebody in the future.

Comment: By stash do you mean `git stash` and `git stash pop`?

Comment: @fatuhoku Yes, I prefer `git stash apply`, because It's more safe.

Comment: @Allen please be detail, i get a `-bash: stash: command not found`.

Comment: @aircraft It's not command code, it's steps reference. Try the command `git add .` -> `git stash` -> `git stash apply` -> `pod install`.